# Porque no me lee el salto de linea en C++?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

No se porque no me lee el salto de linea cuando guardo los nombres al archivo.
Gracias de antemano, quien pueda ayudarme. (Estoy usando codeblocks)

```
    #include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ofstream modificar;
    modificar.open("Documento1.txt",ios::binary);
    char nombrea[10],nombreb[10],nombrec[10];
    cout<<"Ingrese tres nombres"<<endl;
    cin.getline(nombrea,10);
    cin.getline(nombreb,10);
    cin.getline(nombrec,10);
    modificar<<nombrea<<endl<<nombreb<<endl<<nombrec<<endl;
    modificar.close();
    ifstream leer;
    leer.open("Documento1.txt");
    char linea[40];
    leer>>linea;
    cout<<linea;
    leer.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @OmarAlami el resultado es exactamente el mismo. El operador de inserción devuelve una referencia de `modificar`, luego su código y el tuyo son equivalentes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es sustituir las apariciones de `endl` por `"\r\n"`.

`endl` se está traduciendo por `'\n'` y el editor que usas seguramente entienda que el salto de línea se produce ante la secuencia `"\r\n"`.

Además, `endl` suele conllevar una llamada tipo `fflush` que no te aporta absolutamente nada a tu código.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hey excelente! Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resuelto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ofstream modificar;
    modificar.open("Documento1.txt",ios::binary);
    char nombrea[10],nombreb[10],nombrec[10];
    cout<<"Ingrese tres nombres"<<endl;
    cin.getline(nombrea,10);
    cin.getline(nombreb,10);
    cin.getline(nombrec,10);
    modificar<<nombrea<<"\r\n"<<nombreb<<"\r\n"<<nombrec<<"\r\n";
    modificar.close();
    ifstream leer;
    leer.open("Documento1.txt");
    char linea[40];
    leer>>linea;
    cout<<linea;
    leer.close();
    return 0;
}
```